# how to dynamically identify which html element on a page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application page, have a web table with multiple rows and columns loaded dynamically based on the data added. In a one of the "td" the data will be sometimes a "p" tag or "button" tag (but will look like a link) based on the status of the account on that row. And also I need to click that button to do some additional action. Here i need to validate a case, need to take all the rows and columns data and store it. But while on this particular td, as it varies based on the account status, how can I dynamically check and take the status text like check if it is "button" or "p" control?

Table looks like below

[image]

Code for both the rows looks like (sammple)

```
<td class="Table2Cell account-list-cell va--middle pl--2" tabindex="0" style="width: 24%; min-height: 120px; max-height: 120px;">
    <div class="FlexBox FlexBox__direction FlexBox__direction--row FlexBox__justify--start">
        <div class="FlexItem FlexItem__align-self--top FlexItem__align-self--base-top">
            <svg class="Icon status-action Icon--rotate-0 Icon--size-small-tight" focusable="false" name="icon-alert-circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin-top: 2px;">
                <use xlink:href="/static/fonts/icons/icon-defs.svg#alert-circle"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="FlexItem FlexItem__align-self--center FlexItem__align-self--base-center">
            <div style="padding-left: 4px;">
                <button aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Upload Check Image" class="Button px--0 py--0 Button--link" formnovalidate="" type="button" style="min-height: 0px; line-height: 16px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <span class="Button__text Button__text--link">Upload Check Image</span>
                </button>
                <p class="text--dark text--small">Action Required
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>

=============

<td class="Table2Cell account-list-cell va--middle pl--2" tabindex="-1" style="width: 24%; min-height: 120px; max-height: 120px;">
    <div class="FlexBox FlexBox__direction FlexBox__direction--row FlexBox__justify--start">
        <div class="FlexItem FlexItem__align-self--top FlexItem__align-self--base-top">
            <svg class="Icon status-verified Icon--rotate-0 Icon--size-small-tight" focusable="false" name="icon-checkmark-circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin-top: 2px;">
                <use xlink:href="/static/fonts/icons/icon-defs.svg#checkmark-circle"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="FlexItem FlexItem__align-self--center FlexItem__align-self--base-center">
            <div style="padding-left: 4px;">
                <p class="text--regular flex-grow--0">Verified</p>
                <p class="text--dark text--small">Status
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

any help on this?

Comment: irrespective of `p` or `button` will it always have a link ?

Comment: No, if "p" then normal text. If "button" then looks like link, have to click and do some action.

Comment: and what are those `p` and `button` in the shared HTML ? Is that this one `<p class="text--dark text--small">Action Required` and `<p class="text--regular flex-grow--0">Verified</p>` ?

Comment: I don't get your question. Please check the screenshot. you may get it. One is kind of label caption (Action Required, Status), other is the actual status (Verified, Upload Check Image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma in css selectors `button, p.text--regular` return both or existing one element. Using the css selector you'll get `button` or `p`. Parent element should be a row element. Use it to get an element and check the tag.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement statusElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button, p.text--regular")));

String tag = statusElement.getTagName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `Action Required` and `Verified, Status` is in `P` tag. However there's a difference between `Action Required` **p** `tag` and that is it has a `preceding-sibling (button)` that has text `Upload Check Image`.

I have a work around for this Problem (Only cons is that it has a bad time complexity) :

use `findElements()` instead :

**2 cases :**

1. Let's say for most of the time you see `Action Required` the do this :

The below code is for a particular td not a list of tds

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[text()='Upload Check Image']")).size() > 0 ){
        // do what ever you wanna do here when **Action Required** is visible in UI.

}
```

2. When most of the time it is `Verified` :

   ```
   if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'text-- 
      regular') and text() = 'Verified']")).size() > 0 ){
      // do what ever you wanna do here when **Verified** is visible in 
      UI.   
     }
   ```

Comment: so basically you are saying, do the actions based on the label caption either "Status" or "Action Required" am I getting you?

Comment: yes cause any one of them are gonna be there right always ?

Comment: thank you. i have thought this point. but the catch is, as my application is highly dynamic,  tomorrow if they introduce a new caption for different status, i have to add that check in my code. also its like hard coding the label caption inside the java file. I am thinking of how to find dynamically, either whatever the label caption, the actual status is a normal "p" tag or a "button" tag. ?

Comment: you are not hardcoding anything, you are simply using xpaths based out of text.. what's wrong with that ? you will always have to change xpath whenever any UI goes through changes. That is something entire Industry is doing :)